# Solve $2y(x)+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x-t)y(t)dt = g(x)$ using Fourier Transforms

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

I'm unsure if I've managed to get this right here. Taking the Fourier transform of the entire thing, I get $$2Y(k)+Y(k)G(k) = G(k)$$ Since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x-t)y(t)dt$ is the convolution of $y(x)$ and $g(x)$. Solving for $Y(k)$ in terms of $G(k)$ I get $$Y(k) = \frac{G(k)}{2+G(k)}$$

Is the answer really this simple? This just seems too easy, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you need to apply the inverse transform to complete the exercise ?

Comment: No you don't. You just need to solve it in terms of $Y(k)$

Comment: @johnpage your answer seems fine to me